# Javascript: Initialize a variable by condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, one-liner

I want to Initialize a variable type with the Value of a certain Field like that:

```
function checkAfterPrereqChange(blfType, blfId){
    const type = $("#fieldTypeInput"+blfId).val();
}
```

The Thing is that this field only exists if blfType is 'field', if not type should be the value from blfType, like that:

```
function checkAfterPrereqChange(blfType, blfId){
    let type = blfType;
    if (blfType == "field"){
        let type = $("#fieldTypeInput"+blfId).val();
    }
}
```

Can i still do this in only one line and with a const variable?
In Python I would do something like that:

```
type = $("#fieldTypeInput"+blfId).val() if blfType == "field" else blfType
```

Is there a way to do this in Javascript as well?

Answer (score 1):

`const type = blfType === "field" ? $("#fieldTypeInput"+blfId).val() : blfType`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
const type = blfType === "field" ? $("#fieldTypeInput"+blfId).val() : blfType
```